# JavaScript Progress Bar Incrememnet on Button Click Issue Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

This issue I am having is the first time the upload button is clicked, the progress bar is incrementing, however when you press the close button for the modal it will close the modal and again click on the add attachments to open the modal, then press upload again - the progress bar does not increment. I think its an issue with the javascript not looping maybe. Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#reset").click(function() {
    $(':input', '#attachmentModal').val("");
    $("#pbarmain").hide();
    $("#pbar").hide();
  });
});


var i = 0;

function makeProgress() {
  console.log("testing")
  $("#pbarmain").show();
  if (i < 100) {
    i = i + 4;
    $(".progress-bar").css("width", i + "%").text(i + " %");
    setTimeout("makeProgress()", 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="pbarmain" style="display: none" class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div id="pbar" class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
<button type="button" onClick="makeProgress()" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
<button type="button" id="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $(':input','#attachmentModal').val("");
        $("#pbarmain").hide();
        $("#pbar").hide();
        $(".progress-bar").css("width", "0%");
        i = 0;
    });
});
function makeProgress(){
  $("#pbarmain").show();
  $("#pbar").show();
    if(i < 100){
    i = i + 4;
    $(".progress-bar").css("width", i + "%").text(i + " %");
    setTimeout("makeProgress()", 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div  id = "pbarmain" style="display: none" class="progress progress-striped active">
<div id = "pbar" class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" onClick="makeProgress()" class="btn btn-default" >Upload</button>
  <button type="button" id ="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

You didn't set the `i` parameter back to 0 when you closed the modal

Comment: Hi Brent. 
Thanks!

Comment: @RA19 please set this answer as completed  and downvote why ?

Comment: Hi Brent. How do I do that?